# Why is online course enrollment limited to specific times when a course is offered?

Tags: online-learning, mooc

Online course providers like edX and coursera offer free courses, but you can only take/enroll the courses at specific times of the year (not any time). Why is that? If you just want to learn something (not for a degree in accredited institutions), it would be much easier if you could do it online anytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually for both of them some courses are fully autonomous "anytime" courses, while others are restricted to being offered at particular times.  So far as I can tell, the time-restricted courses derive two benefits from being time-restricted:

1. It creates a "cohort" of students learning similar things and doing similar assignments at the same time, who can then help one another in the associated forums.
2. Resources needed to support the course (e.g., TA monitoring, course material updates) can track the progress of the students through the course, increasing the return on resources and minimizing disruption to students.

Comment: There are also self-paced courses out there, e.g. MIT OpenCourseWare (OCW), or the still-relevant traditional technology known as "books" (ask your library for details). Of course, with these, you miss out on the specific advantages of MOOCs that jakebeal describes.

Answer (score -1):

You kind find two type of courses.

1. Self-paced: When you select this type of courses you can enroll and take these courses any time of the year.
2. But the live courses will enable you to enroll only twice or thrice a year. This is because this type of courses will be conducted for large amount of students at the same time. That's known as MOOC-Massive open online course.

Comment: I have removed the link since it doesn't seem to provide any value to the post and makes it seem like spam. If you want to add the link back in, please expand on it and explain why it is relevant. That way if the link ever dies, the value of your answer will not decrease.

Comment: What does this add to the previous answer by jakebeal?